# How to know if a graphic card is shader 2 compatible?

Tags: graphics-card

I have no access to the cards for the moment. I only have their names:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller 

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge Integrated Graphics Controller
```

My guess is that the 00:02.0 means yes, but I'm not sure.

thanks

Comment: 00:02.0 refers to the device address. Of course you’d need to consult the specifications for each GPU.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA), yes.

```
GMA 3100

Integrated graphics found on G31 and G33 chipset motherboards. Shader Model 3.0,
support Pixel Shader 2.0 and doesn't support Vertex Shader with OpenGL 1.4 support.
```